# SQL Server 2008 Query Group Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create an SQL Query that will be displayed on a windows Application in vb.net and then extracted to an excel file. I have two tables in SQL Server 2008. Below are images of my two tables.

Table 1: [image]

and Table 2:[image]

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

But do this in 1 query and include Table2.Date.

My 2 queries right now are these:

```html
SELECT Table1.Id AS Z_Number,SUM(Table2.Amount) AS Cash_Payments, COUNT(Table2.TicketId)AS No_of_Tickets
FROM Table2,Table1
where Table2.Name='Cash' and Table2.Date between  Table1.StartDate and Table1.EndDate and Table1.Id=1
GROUP BY Table1.Id
SELECT Table1.Id AS Z_Number,SUM(Table2.Amount) AS Credit_Card_Payments, COUNT(Table2.TicketId)AS No_of_Tickets
FROM Table2,Table1
where Table2.Name='Credit Card' and Table2.Date between  Table1.StartDate and Table1.EndDate and Table1.Id=1
GROUP BY Table1.Id
```

Any advice on what exact query function I can use to achieve it?

Required Result:
[image]

Comment: you want as 2 rows or 1 row with cash & credit payment in separate column ? Can you show us how the required result looks like ?

Comment: What is `z_number`?  The logic for producing your results is not obvious.

Comment: 2 rows. Z_number is basically Table1.Id

Comment: edited the question for required result @Squirrel

Comment: a quick way is to use `UNION ALL` add it between the 2 query

Comment: This actually does work fine. The only thing missing is the Table2.Date @Squirrel

Comment: Column 'Table2.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: there might be multiple payment date per Z-Number, so which one you want to show ? You can use MIN() or MAX() to show either one of them

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This gives me the right result. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.